# Q: Android Dev - Permission Check/Req for Multiple Permissions - is this correct?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions, android-permissions

**Hey everyone, thank you for assisting with my Question..**

I'm attempting to implement the new Permissions request in an App for the first time, so I just need a tiny bit of help..

Basically, my step 1 involves checking to see if the permission is already granted, and then request it in the next step if its not already granted.. 
**But I need to check and make sure ALL the permissions I need are granted, not just one..** 
So heres what I have for checking the one single permission:

```
private void checkPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Permission already available, continue to Method "finishPermissionCheck"
        finishPermissionCheck();

    } else {
        // Permission needs to be requested, continue to Method "requestPermission"
        requestPermission();
    }
}
```

Ok so, this is fine for only ONE Permission, but I need to check for **MULTIPLE** Permissions (and if needed, request multiple Permissions).. I tried using && to include the rest of the Permissions, but to no avail.. I also tried creating a String of multiple Permissions, as shown below..
**This is what my attempt looks like..**
First I create a string of multiple Permissions in the scope (in this case, I'm just trying 2 Permissions):

```
private static final String[] requiredPermissions = {
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
};
```

Then I changed the Permission Check code to look like this:

```
private void checkPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, String.valueOf(requiredPermissions))
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Permission already available, continue to Method "finishPermissionCheck"
        finishPermissionCheck();

    } else {
        // Permission needs to be requested, continue to Method "requestPermission"
        requestPermission();
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure if this is correct way to do this..
**What would be the best way to accomplish this task?**

..And Yes Moderators, I've taken a look around at the other posts related to this topic.

Thanks a ton ahead of time for any help!

Answer (score 0):

in your `finishPermissionCheck();` method call this following code ->

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SendMoneyByDetailsActivity.this, requiredPermissions , REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you would suggest I add that line of code you suggested (to requestPermissions) to my 'finishPermissionCheck();' method, considering that's the method I call once I've already verified success of Permission checks.. If theres something I'm missing about your suggestion, please explain.. otherwise ill assume theres been a miscommunication.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I faced the same problem recently. I will share my implementation. In my case I needed to check for all TWO permissions but it looks scalable to me.

MyPermissionHandler.java

```
// return true if all permissions are granted
public boolean getPermissions() {
    // if version is smaller, the permissions in the xml file are enough
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return true;
    }

    // create an array list with needed permissions if they are not granted already
    ArrayList<String> perms = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        if(!hasCameraPermission()) add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if(!hasWritePermission()) add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }};

    if(perms.size()>0) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, perms.toArray(new String[0]), MainActivity.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

private boolean hasCameraPermission() {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
private boolean hasWritePermission() {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

In the MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    // if at least one permission is denied, finish the activity
    for(int permission : grantResults) {
        if(permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Error")
                    .setMessage("This application needs all permissions.")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();

            return;
        }
    }

    // all permissions are granted
}
```

If you need to add more permissions you must only change the code in the `MyPermissionHandler.java` file. Hope this helps! :)

BTW, you can add some checking in the onResume() method of the activity, in case of when a user minimizes the program and goes to settings to disable, for instance, the camera permission. After he goes back to the application and the app tries to open the camera, the app will crash. So you must be careful.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks for taking the time to create such a killer response for me! :) I haven't tested it yet, but once I do test it (soon) I'll be sure to make it the accepted answer, and credit you for such a great effort. The only thing I'm worried about is: I need a Permission that allows me to turn the "Location" Setting to OFF.. But I'm pretty sure It's a Secure Setting, which can't be changed ("read only"). However I'm looking into the Google API's trying to figure out how I might be able to do it via a System Prompt for the user to ok it (without user needing to go to settings screen)

Comment: As far as I know, you can't "toggle" the location sensor on/off. I once had to enable the setting "Unknown sources" which enables apps that are not from Google Play Store to install other apps(I needed this so I could do auto-updates). But I didn't find a way to do it with a prompt or any permission I could ask, so I opened the settings menu where the setting was for the user and "hoped" he will find the right setting. If you find anything that helps you with the Location sensor, please feel free to share it. :) @StudioB

Comment: QUESTION: What about using the SettingsAPI from Google? I think it may be possible to request changing the Setting, and have a System-Dialog pop up to ask permission to change it, similar to what the Maps app does.. Do you know anything about this? @Zdravko Donev